# html5 click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a click event to a shape using jquery and html5...but instead of only the shape the entire canvas is clickable. Need some help with this. This is the project

http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/click.html

Comment: we need to see some code, also the whole document is clickable so far

Comment: you can access the code by clicking on the link and just viewing the source...and yes...that exactly is my question....how to stop the whole document being clickable..that is my question

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some custom code to handle mouse events inside the canvas. Have a look at the "Mouse Events" part of this [tutorial](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes) which handle a similar solution as you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have seen this article before, his example works but the code is extremely convoluted...i am loosing track of it

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure:

1. Paint the shape in an offscreen layer (another canvas) with a transparent background (fill with rgba(0,0,0,0).
2. Read canvas click X, Y positions from canvas.onclick event.
3. Check the offscreen layer x, y coordinates:

   - if layer(x,y) = rgba(0,0,0,0) then the click was outside the shape.
   - else shape was clicked.

Comment: can you give me little bit more detail? I am having a hard time following your solution

Comment: which part? It's really simple.